# Laravel Livewire getting error message from validator in component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

in my `register` form i have a `username` input field into the form and i want to only validate it with this below rule:

```
'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|min:5|max:15|unique:users'
```

and i want to get validation error and send it with another way to view instead of using `bags` message in view like with `Laravel` implementation. for example:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control"
       name="username"
       wire:model="username"
       value="{{old('username')}}">
```

component:

```php
    public function updatedUsername($username)
    {
        //$validator = $this->validate(['username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|min:5|max:15|unique:users']);

        $validator = $this->validateOnly($username,['username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|min:5|max:15|unique:users']);

        if ($validator->fail()) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

in this `Component` how can i get validation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `validate()`/`validateOnly()`, an exception will be thrown if the validation fails. Laravel will intercept this validation error to handle it in the blade-template, for features like `@error('fieldName')`.

In order to hook into the validation in "real-time" with Livewire, you need to catch that exception. To get the real-time validation with `@error('fieldName')`, you should also re-throw the exception once you are done.

```php
public function updated($field)
{
    try {
        $this->validateOnly($field);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
        // Do your thing and use $validator here
        $validator = $e->validator;

        // ...

        // Once you're done, re-throw the exception
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

As you probably may have noticed, there is no definition of any of the rules here. That's because they should be defined in the protected property `$rules` your class (*unless you have a really compelling reason to leave it out of the global ruleset for that component*).

```
class Foo extends Component
{
    protected $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|min:5|max:15|unique:users'
    ];
    
    // ....
}
```

If you ever need to introduce other properties or use functions into the rules, you can remove the property and declare a `rules()` method instead - this isn't as well documented, so might be a bit obscure.

```
class Foo extends Component
{
    public function rules() 
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|min:5|max:15|unique:users'
        ];
    }
}
```

Sidenote: Instead of using a regex, you may want to use the [`alpha`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-alpha) rule instead.

Comment: as you say to check validation in component and getting catch, my question is if we had more validation how can i validate them? for example `username` is one of my form fields and i have some other `input` into form, how can i validate them like with `username` realtime?

Comment: Just define the rules like you do with the username (as a key/value array), then rename `updatedUsername($field)`  to `updated($field)`. The rules are just as any Laravel validation rule-array.

Comment: my question is can i use multiple rule and validate form fields one by one instead of validate all fields with one action?

Comment: Yes, using `validateOnly` you only validate that one, particular field, you just send the name of the field in to that method.

Comment: very good, can you update your post with a sample how can i do that? thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You **don't** have to check for `if ($validator->fails())` [livewire does that for you](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation).

If validation fails, a standard ValidationException is thrown (and caught by Livewire), and the standard $errors object is available inside the component's view. Because of this, any existing code you have, likely a Blade include, for handling validation in the rest of your application will apply here as well.

Just add this in your blade file (preferably after input tag)

```
@error('username')
    <div class="error-label">
        {{ $message }}
    </div>
@enderror
```

Comment: by default i'm using this solution and as i said i don't want to use this solution and i try to get message inside component not view, because i want to work with errors before showing in view